# Am I using a while loop wrong?

Tags: shell-script

I found a list of projects to do, and one of them was something that generates amounts of change. I made this code:

```
getamt() {
echo "Enter amount of money."
read amount
echo "OK."
}
change() {
amount=$(echo "$amount*100" | bc)
quarter=$(echo "($amount-25)" | bc)
dime=$(echo "($amount-10)" | bc)
nickel=$(echo "($amount-5)" | bc)
penny=$(echo "($amount-1)" | bc )
quarter=${quarter%???}
dime=${dime%???}
nickel=${nickel%???}
penny=${penny%???}
amount=${amount%???}
qNum=0
dNum=0
nNum=0
pNum=0
}

getchange() {
while [ $quarter -ge 0 ]
do
qNum=$(( qNum+1 ))
amount=$(( $amount-25 ))
done
while [ $dime -ge 0 ]
do
dNum=$(( dNum+1 ))
amount=$(( $amount-10 ))
done
while [ $nickel -ge 0 ]
do
nNum=$(( nNum+1 ))
amount=$(( $amount-5 ))
done
while [ $penny -ge 0 ]
do
pNum=$(( nNum+1 ))
amount=$(( $amount-1 ))
done
}

display() {
echo "Your change is:"
echo "$qNum quarters"
echo "$dNum dimes"
echo "$nNum nickels"
echo "$pNum pennies"
}

getamt
change
getchange
display
```

I know it's probably a bad way of doing what I need to do, but it's getting stuck.
I think I may have used the `while` loop wrong, but I don't know.
My objective in using the `while` loops were to check if it's possible to add another type of that coin there, so it checks if the value is above zero.

Comment: You should use indentation to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code's most obvious issue is that all of your `while` loops check a variable (e.g. `$quarter`) that is never changed inside the loop, so the loop condition can never become false and the loop repeats endlessly.

Let's look at one of the loops:

```
while [ $quarter -ge 0 ]
do
qNum=$(( qNum+1 ))
amount=$(( $amount-25 ))
done
```

If `$quarter` > 0, the control flow enters the loop, `$qNum` is incremented and `$amount` is decremented, but `$quarter` remains unchanged, so you're in for another loop iteration.

---

Fixing your code works best by restructuring it:

- Instead of relying on global variables like `amount` that are set as side effects of functions, rewrite your functions to accept parameters and output their results to `stdout` (where possible).

  - Results to `stdout`: Your function `getamt()` could `echo $amount` instead of relying on `amount` being available (and unchanged) for processing later on in the script. Whatever calls `getamt` can then capture this output into a variable with `amount=$(getamt)`.
    Unfortunately that doesn't work as well when a function needs to return multiple values — in that case, you could have the function print its return values separated by newlines or a character that you know won't appear in the values. You could even go for an output format like

    ```
    quarter=3  
    dime=1  
    nickel=4
    ```

    and evaluate that output to set local variables with the function's return values: `$(yourfunction); echo $quarter`
  - Parameters: Your function `change()` could take the amount of change it should compute as a parameter (i.e. you would call `amount 2.50`) instead of reading it from a global variable. You can access parameters given to your function (or to your script, depending on the context) via their indices: `$1` for the first parameter, `$2` for the second one, etc.
- You can avoid a few calls to `bc` by just cutting off the decimal places *once* and only using bash arithmetic evaluation after that. Your current substitution `${quarter%???}` also removes *any* last three characters, which is going to yield unwanted results if your users ever decide to enter a value with more (or less) than two decimal places. Use something like `${quarter%%.*}` to remove everything after (and including) the first `.`.
- Use comments (started with a `#` and continued until the end of the line):
  e.g. `amount=${amount%%.*}  # remove decimal places`
  Most of your code will seems obvious to you right now, but it might not be obvious to anyone else looking at it, and it also won't be obvious for you anymore when you'll have to look at it again in a few months.
- To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how your script is supposed to calculate the number of coins to return at the moment. The most common approach to calculating change would be a greedy algorithm that starts at the highest available coin value, dispenses as many coins of that value as "fit" into the change amount **<sup>1</sup>**, subtracts the total value of those coins from the change amount, then continues with the next (smaller) coin value, and so on, until the change amount reaches 0 (i.e. enough coins have been dispensed to make up the total change amount).
  <sub>**<sup>1</sup>** To compute this number of coins, you can either look at [modulo operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) or just subtract the current coin value from the change amount in a loop until the change amount is smaller than the coin value (i.e. you would return too much change if you dispensed another coin of the current value).</sub>

Comment: +1 for a lot of good advice.  One thing I would disagree with: shell function return values are treated modulo 256, so `return $amount` will fail for amount > $2.55.

Comment: @Scott You're right, that wasn't such a good idea. I've replaced it with a suggestion to use `stdout` to convey one or multiple return values from a function.

Comment: A function that prints all values to stdout might be used like: `: "$(($(fn)))"` to set all values at once in the current shell - it might be used that way, that is, if the coder can be *very* sure of the function in the first place. Still, `$((n&255))` is more than enough of a range to work with for any competent programmer wishing to convey a coin count which can never optimally exceed - what? - nine? And I think the worst case is 99. *(Although no shell function should ever return >=127 anyway - those returns are for signals)*.

Answer (score 3):

Of the two shell functions below, the actual math is just done here:

```
while   set     "${1#0?}" "${1#?}"
        shift   "$((!${#1}))"
        [ "${1:-0}" -gt 0 ]
do      case    $1 in   ([3-9]?|2[5-9])
                set "$(($1%25))" "$((q+=$1/25))";;
        (??)    set "$(($1%10))" "$((d=$1/10))" ;;
        (?)     set "" "$((p=$1-(5*(n=$1>=5))))";;
esac;   done
```

That's all of the coin selection code - it's optimized to return as few coins as possible. And I didn't have to do anything to make it so because that's how the `case` shell control statement works - by selecting only the earliest possible match. So all that is necessary is to put the coins in order from largest to smallest and you'll never exceed 3 iterations.

The only difficult part about the above is protecting portable shell math from misinterpreting the results as an octal in the case of 08 and 09. That's handled by squeezing away any leading zeroes once each loop run.

In fact, considering that your stated goal is to take input from and provide output to an interactive user, the majority of the functions below are focused mainly on input validation and error reporting. That's some important stuff, too - especially where shell math is concerned. Because shell math is essentially a 2-part `eval` operation, when you put user input in an arithmetic statement you should probably first ensure you know what you've got there.

`case` is, again, my goto form for such things.

```
_err()( unset   parm    msg     IFS     \
                "${1##*[!_[:alnum:]]*}" || exit
        parm=$1 IFS=$2  msg=$3; shift   3
        eval ': "${'"$parm?\"'\$*' can't be right. \$msg"'"}"'
)
_chg()  if      set -- "${1#"${1%%[!0]*}"}.${2%"${2#??}"}${3+.}" "$@" &&
                case    $1      in
                (*.*.*) shift
                        _err    too_many_dots   .       "
                        We're fresh out of microcoins."         "$@"    ;;
                (-*)    shift
                        _err    nice_try_pal    .       "
                        Change isn't magic money, you know."    "$@"    ;;
                (*[!0-9.]*)     shift
                        _err    i_hate_poetry   .       "
                        We only spend numbers around here."     "$@"    ;;
                (.00|.0|.)      shift
                        _err    that_was_easy   .       "
                        Next time try spending something."      0 00    ;;
                esac || return
        then    set     "${1##*.}" "$((q=(${1%%.*}0*4)/10+(d=(n=(p=0)))))"
                while   set     "${1#0?}" "${1#?}"
                        shift   "$((!${#1}))"
                        [ "${1:-0}" -gt 0 ]
                do      case    $1 in   ([3-9]?|2[5-9])
                        set "$(($1%25))" "$((q+=$1/25))";;
                (??)    set "$(($1%10))" "$((d=$1/10))" ;;
                (?)     set "" "$((p=$1-(5*(n=$1>=5))))";;
                esac;   done
                set     quarter q dime d nickel n penny p
                echo    Your change is:
                while   [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
                do      printf "\t$1 coins:\t$(($2))\n"
                        shift   2
        done;   fi
```

It doesn't actually `read` any input, though, and only takes input as command line arguments. You can pull user input with something like:

```
printf '\n$  '; IFS=. read -r dollars cents dot
```

And directly pass that along like...

```
_chg "$dollars" "$cents" ${dot:+""}
```

...and all of the rest should be automatic.

The `_err()` function is a reusable function I wrote which you might use here or elsewhere for error reporting with proper return. When you expand an `unset` `${var?expansion form}` the shell will print *expansion form* to stderr and abruptly exit with error status. This is not a behavior which typically works well for tests of the kind you might like to handle on your own, but if you know that some condition which must be met in order for that `unset` parameter to expand at all is definitely a condition which means your process *should* die, then it can be a very convenient way to go. This is because the shell formats all of the output in its own, standard way *(to which your interactive shell user is probably already accustomed)*, and handles your exit code at once.

For example:

```
bash -c '. ~/coins.sh
         _err parameter_name \
              -splitter      \
              "Some custom message that is also thrown in." \
              and my entire input arg array
'
```

...when run at the command-line returns 1 and prints to stderr...

```
/home/mikeserv/coins.sh: line 5: parameter_name: 'and-my-entire-input-arg-array' can't be right. Some custom message that is also thrown in.
```

And so the entire top half of of `_chg()` is devoted to verifying input is what it should be or returning an error condition and error output when it is not.

The last quarter of same is devoted to formatting stdout when all goes well like:

```
sh -c '. ~/coins.sh; _chg 10 97'
Your change is:
    quarter coins:  43
    dime coins:     2
    nickel coins:   0
    penny coins:    2
```

Comment: The coin counting is great! It took me a while to get my head around it :) +1

Comment: @Peter.O - now *that* is a compliment indeed.

Comment: Thanks again for making another bit of code for me to look around and use. :D

Comment: -1 in my opinion this is an ugly peace of code.: strange formatting,  use of $1 throughought the code instead of a named variable and some other things.

Comment: Beauty is definitely in the eye of the beholder... It's good to have you back Mike !

Comment: @don_crissti - not back. just passing through, and i was thinking about some codes

Answer (score 2):

Another answer has addressed your specific issue. I baulked after a while of trying to sort it out. So, here is another approach for you to consider - with one `while` and one `until` and one `for` loop.  Arrays help to simplify the code.

```
 echo "Enter amount of money: $.c or just $"
 read amount
 echo

 a=(${amount/./ })  # change '.' to ' ' and make an array: a[0], a[1]
 da=${a[0]}         # dollar-amount 
 pa=$((10#${a[1]})) # penny-amount
 cv=(25 10 5 1)     # array of coin-values  cv[0] ... cv[3] - q d n p
 cc=(\  \  \  \ )   # array of coin-counts  cc[0] ... cc[3] - q d n p
 cn=( quarters dimes nickels pennies ) # array of coin-names
 while (( pa > 0 )); do
     for (( i=0; i<${#cv[@]}; i++ )); do  # process coin-types from hi-val to lo-val
         (( (pa-cv[i]) < 0 )) && continue # look-ahead: don't give too much change
         (( (pa-=cv[i]) ))                # decrement penny-amount
         (( cc[i]+=1 ))                   # increment coin-type counters
     done
 done
 # 'paste' arrrays side by side, and tabulate via 'column' 
 echo "Your coins change is:"  # and show only relevant coins via 'sed'  
 column -t <(paste  <(printf '%s\n' "${cn[@]}") \
                    <(printf '%s\n' "${cc[@]}")) | sed -n '/[0-9]/p'
```

Comment: Interesting Approach, but I'm missing the concept, ie how does i know which type of coin to increment? Does `pa-=` move the pointer?

Comment: I've modiried the answer, since you posted the comment. -- Now ther are 2 `pa` arithmetic evaluations.  1) `(( (pa-cv[i]) < 0 ))` for which `pa-cv[i]` does **not** modify the value of `pa`; the result of the evaluation is used it the test for `< 0` ... however in 2) `(( (pa-=cv[i]) ))`, the value of  `pa` **does** change. The `-=` means *pa* = *itself* - *cv[i]*

Comment: Regarding, *"which type of coin to increment?* - The `cv` array contains the coin-values in *largest-to-smallest* order. The `for`-loop itterates over this array from the *0'th* array element (*quarters*) on down to the lowest value element (*pennies*).  Within this *for*-loop, the *until*-loop increments the current element's counter, *until* it detects that the next coin (of the current value) will be *one-coin-too-many* - at which point it exits the *until*-loop and continues on with the next itteration of the *for*-loop, ie. with the next lower-valued coin, etc. - (bash arrays are 0-based)

Comment: updated - the `until` loop was wrong - got rid of it  and used a condition test instead